# Getting information several tables with same id

Tags: php, mysql

I have several tables linked with the field id. What I want to do is get all the informations from all tables accessing via `id` fields.

What I have tried (without success) is this:

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM mv_user_info 
    INNER JOIN mv_user_password
        ON mv_user_password.uid = mv_user_info.uid     
    INNER JOIN mv_user_lang_interested
        ON mv_user_lang_interested.uid = mv_user_info.uid        
    INNER JOIN mv_user_disponibility
        ON mv_user_disponibility.uid = mv_user_info.uid      
    WHERE mv_user_info.uid = '$uid'
") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: And what does "without success" mean?  Are you getting an error?  Incorrect data?

Comment: The variable results returns 0. If the query only contains the first INNER-JOIN the variable results returns all the values from the table user_info and user_password with the same id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks fine -- although I cannot vouch for the names of the tables or columns.  Perhaps the problem is that the user is missing rows in one of the tables.  Then, nothing will match the `inner join`, and no rows will come back.

Try `left join` instead:

```
SELECT * FROM mv_user_info 
LEFT JOIN mv_user_password
    ON mv_user_password.uid = mv_user_info.uid     
LEFT JOIN mv_user_lang_interested
    ON mv_user_lang_interested.uid = mv_user_info.uid        
LEFT JOIN mv_user_disponibility
    ON mv_user_disponibility.uid = mv_user_info.uid      
WHERE mv_user_info.uid = '$uid';
```